# Get values of hidden column for a selected row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview with 1 hidden column and 6 columns. I am trying to get the value of the hidden column row when the user clicks the button within the row but it does not pick up the hidden column. It gets the value of the first column which is the first visible column(FirstName).

Is there a way to get the value of the hidden column(UserID) ?

This is what I have:

C#

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-bordered" ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyNames="UserID, Firstname" OnRowCommand="gvUsers_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gvUsers_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" Visible="false" HeaderText="UserID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Cellphone Number" SortExpression="EventDescription" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="EventDescription" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=btnTest]').on("click", function () {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
            alert(id);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please assist how I can get the hidden column value when the button is clicked. Thank you.

Comment: That is because the hidden column does not exist in the html. When you set a control to Visible=false it does not get rendered to the client.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to get the UserID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just add it to a TemplateField in an element that is hidden

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span style="display:none"><%# Eval("UserID") %></span>

        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And modify the script to

```
var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('span').html();
```

Update

As @Taplar mentioned, you can also use attributes. But you need to add those in the RowDataBound event.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

    e.Row.Attributes.Add("data-userid", row["userid"].ToString());
}
```

The script would then become

```
var id = $(this).closest("tr").data('userid');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Just so I know, what if I have 2 or more hidden TemplateFields? How do I get the value for each span TemplateFields?

Comment: @Taplar, yes it does. But you need to add a method for that with the RowDataBound event. I can add it if you want...

Comment: @Taplar, you are right. It is easier and cleaner with attibutes. Updated my answer,

Comment: Thank you for this